# Can I use VUE router in Multiple-Pages-Application?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, vue-router, vue-cli

I am working on a Marketplace project using VUE CLI and I was wondering if I can use both the advantages of Vue router and MPA approach at once...
for instance: Vue router for simple pages like **About** & **Contact Us**...    & MPA for more complex pages like different sections...

Theoretically , I think it's possible but I'm wondering if it's recommended !

Comment: It's hard to say if it's recommended if the reasons why it should be done one way and not another is not known.

Comment: I think the main reason is simplicity, like why would create a whole new page when I can just change the content of an already created page ! But i get if the page is kinda complex I do need a whole new page, that's why I thought about using both.. Is it common to use both ?

Comment: It's more or less common but it's based on practical needs, like sub-apps are developed by different teams, or use different sets of dependencies, or different frameworks, or else. It's unclear why 'complex' demands to have it in another app. The complexity is likely irrelevant if the app was designed properly.